# Query returns empty results with BigQuery/User permissions but correct results with BigQuery/Admin permissions

Tags: google-bigquery

When I perform query under service account with BigQuery/User permissions I get empty results, there are no errors but results are empty. If I change permissions of service account to BigQuery/Admin I get correct results back. If permissions are insufficient I would expect error pop-up instead of empty results.
I can't post the query. Query consists of one DECLARE/SET operator and one SELECT with ARRAY_AGG and subquery.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) but may be more complex that I initially thought.

To check my theory I created a service account with the role BigQuery user and ran the following commands from a new instance:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=[KEY_FILE]

bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 'SELECT
   COUNT(*)
 FROM
   `bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare'
```

it worked well and returned the proper result.

I checked that I was using the proper account by running:

```
gcloud auth list
```

Furthermore, in the documentation it states that "For any job you create, you automatically have the equivalent of the bigquery.jobs.get and bigquery.jobs.update permissions for that job." Meaning, if you are able to run a query you should be able to retrieve the results for it.

Can you check if querying public data yields the proper result for you or still blank results while using the BQ User service account?

Note: I realized that specifying a service account in the bq query call had been [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#deprecated_bq_authorization_flags), so I had to recheck doing it the proper way

Comment: So why would I get `bigquery.jobs.create` permission exception in case of lets say DataViewer user role but empty results in this case? Is this by design and documented somewhere?

Comment: I modified my answer. As per the error message it shows when you lack permissions to run the query. BigQuery User has the necessary permissions to run a query therefore no error message will show up. Why you do not retrieve the results may need further research. You can test if the query indeed runs by saving the results in some "dummy" table.